# Behaviour of CSS float, float to first instead if previous

Tags: html, css, css-float

I do know the way a float behaves. The top of the next block needs to be higher than the bottom of the previous block when it has to go to the next line. I however, need it to float to the first block from the previous level.

Currently I am working with really large menus with lists of different sizes and I am getting a lot of whitespaces because of the floats. I need an easy, CSS/HTML based way to solve this.

If you're not sure what I'm talking about, here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2EGbx/1/

As you can see, `five` is all the way to the bottom, leaving a lot of whitespace underneath `one`. I need `five` to go underneath `one`.

I have been googeling for some time now and I really can't find any solutions on this. I'd rather not have a javascript solution because I'm pretty sure CSS can handle it, but if it really is the only way, feel free to suggest.

Comment: you should look for a javascript library to do this, its not possible with pure css, float simply doesn't work that way

Comment: This is not possible because your four and two are larger then one. It works as a block so five can never float above four and two. See this fiddle so it's clear: http://jsfiddle.net/2EGbx/2/ As you can see. Element four is just above element five.

Comment: You need [masonary](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created my own javascript solution.

This script creates 4 columns and puts the list item in the smallest column and then continues on to the next. This is the most efficient way I found\

```
function reformatMenu()
{
    jQuery("#mainmenu td").each(function(index, elem)
    {
        jQuery("body").append('<div id="tempwrap"></div>');
        var $tempWrapper = jQuery("body").find("#tempwrap");
        var $menuwrapper = jQuery(this).find(".subwrapper");
        $tempWrapper.append('<div class="menu_wrapper"><ul></ul></div><div class="menu_wrapper"><ul></ul></div><div class="menu_wrapper"><ul></ul></div><div class="menu_wrapper"><ul></ul></div>');

        $menuwrapper.find("li.level-2").each(function(index, elem)
        {
            var $smallestWrapper = $tempWrapper.find(".menu_wrapper").first();
            $tempWrapper.find(".menu_wrapper").each(function(index, elem)
            {
                if(jQuery(this).height() < $smallestWrapper.height())
                {
                    $smallestWrapper = jQuery(this);
                }
            });
            jQuery(this).appendTo($smallestWrapper.children("ul"));
        });

        $tempWrapper.children().appendTo($menuwrapper);
    });
}
reformatMenu();
```

I'm sure it could be more efficient, but this is my initial idea and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not need to support IE, you can maybe use: on `.outer`

```
-webkit-column-count: 3;  
-webkit-column-gap: 0px;
-moz-column-count: 3;     
-moz-column-gap: 0px; 
column-count: 3;
column-gap: 0px;
```

and on `.outer div`:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle? I can't seem to get it to work correctly. I do need to support IE, but people just need to realise that some things aren't as good in IE, so in all honesty I don't mind letting IE for what it is now ;)

Comment: I just test it in JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2EGbx/7/. There is three columns, but only two are filled, since there is not enough data, but if you add just a little more, like: http://jsfiddle.net/2EGbx/8/, the you will see the 3 columns layout in action.

Answer (score 0):

If the website is not responsive, give each of these element a fixed height and it would be fine, even if it is responsive, I think this is vertical stuff and for the most part would remain the same. However, if you want to do it the right way, don't use float at all, that is not what you want... You need to work around by using `display: inline-block;` or inline or block...

Answer (score 0):

i have changed both of your mark up and css..these are

```
<div class="outer">
 <div class="section">
   <div class="one">one<br/>one</div>
   <div class="five">five</div>
 </div>
   <div class="two">two<br/>two<br/>two<br/>two<br/>two</div>
   <div class="three">three<br/>three<br/>three</div>
   <div class="four">four<br/>four</div>
</div>
```

and css

```
.outer div {
width: 100px;
float:left;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.five{clear:both;}
.section{overflow:hidden;}

.outer {
width: 300px;
}
```

your updated fiddle:: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2EGbx/4/)**

Comment: You've changed the order and wrapped some in a div. This is unfortunately something I can't do since the lists are dynamically created. Otherwise it would be a great solution!